# SQL restricted set of combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations, restrict

I have a table with columns A,B,C and I'd like to get all combinations of records having {B,C} unique. 
That is both B value and C value will appear only once in one set.

Do you have any ideas how to achieve that? I assume the output has to contain one combination on a single row, which is not a problem.

To make it clear here is an example:

- 1,1,0
- 6,1,1
- 1,1,2
- 3,2,0
- 5,2,1
- 1,2,3

One possible combination is {1,1,0},{1,2,3}, while {6,1,1},{5,2,1} isn't, because the C column value '1' is not unique. What I'd like to get is such an output:

```
1,1,0,1,2,3

6,1,1,1,2,3
```

IOW the output will be n-tuples having B,C values unique.

Comment: Is  `SELECT DISTINCT B, C FROM MyTable` what you are after?

Comment: OK, so you want all pairs (A1, B1, C1), (A2, B2, C2) such that B1 != B2 and C1 != C2 ?

Comment: That's right, actually they won't be pairs, but n-tuples. This is just an example.

Comment: @user965748 . . . If I understand correctly, this is quite an unusal request.  Would you mind briefly explaining what you are working on?

Comment: I'd like to get aggregated value of A for each possible combination

Comment: It sounds like the example provided isn't really representative of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to work up an answer based on it, but maybe it will inspire somebody else - a recursive function (or Stored Procedure) call could implement a depth first traversal building a recordset of all rows that don't match the B or C in any row already in the set. Flag the recordsets with GroupNumbers as you build them and add them to a total result. You'd have to order the list and pass position in that list as an argument. Definitely better suited to a procedural language than to SQL, but SQL could do it. It's an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a strange verson of a self join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.b <> t2.b and t1.c <> t2.c;
```

This will return all pairs from the table where the `b` columns have distinct values and the `c` columns have distinct values.

Comment: It seems this is the only way to go, to create a big set of self joins

Comment: If the set is larger, it would be almost impossible to write the statement manually, so one just needs to write a simple PHP or whatever script to generate the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

This is what group by is for.  It combines all records with the same values in the group by list into a single row.

```
select B, C
from my_table
group by B, C
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, if you want just the values of B & C use solution by  @Linger, if you want all fields for records that have a B,C combination that occurs in that record but nowhere else, use

```
SELECT MAX(A),B,C FROM T
GROUP BY B,C
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```